# How to create a struct with auto scheduler?

Tags: go

My goal is to clean the `map[string]time.Time` from expired keys automatically instead of manual loop check. The expected result is that the `key` automatically delete itself instead of getting checked and deleted every 1 minute.

The current solution is `do a loop and check it one by one`:

1. create the `var addrs = map[string]time.Time{}`
2. start a goroutine and rely on `for {}` and `time.Sleep()`.

```
var addrs = map[string]time.Time{}

func StartCleanExpiredAddrs() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
        for addr, val := range addrs {
            if time.Now().After(val) {
                delete(addrs, addr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
func main() {
  go StartCleanExpiredAddrs()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you could do is set up a timer that will tick when you want to expire the item. You should avoid this though if you are planning to store many items because it will need to consume more memory to store the goroutine that will be waiting for the timer Tick.

you can find the simple example I created here:
https://go.dev/play/p/cXdTXKUwJcf

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // init cache
    cache := NewCacheWithExpiry()
    cache.addItem("key1", time.Now().Add(time.Second*5))
    cache.addItem("key2", time.Now().Add(time.Second*3))

    time.Sleep(time.Second*10)
}

type customCacheWithExpiry struct {
    addrs sync.Map
}

func NewCacheWithExpiry() *customCacheWithExpiry{
    return &customCacheWithExpiry{
        addrs: sync.Map{},
    }
}

func (c *customCacheWithExpiry) addItem(key string, val time.Time){
    fmt.Printf("storing key %s which expires at %s\n",key,val)
    c.addrs.Store(key, val)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(val.Sub(time.Now()))
    go func() {
        <-ticker.C
        fmt.Printf("deleting key %s\n", key)
        c.addrs.Delete(key)
    }()
}
```

Comment: It is interesting that you use `sync.Map`. In your case because it does use goroutine, I assume it is necessary. Can I have your opinion regarding `sync.Map` used on my `StartCleanExpiredAddrs` function?

Comment: Yeah in my example above I have to use sync.Map because otherwise if you use a normal hashmap and you try to access it at the same time the application will panic. The same applies in your function, currently in your code it won't be an issue but I would guess that at some point you might want to read from this map and it could cause your application to crash

Comment: So if you want to keep your `StartCleanExpiredAddrs` I would suggest also to switch to sync.Map or use mutex (but sync.Map should be more performant)

Comment: I read the map every time there is a HTTP request. I believe at some point it will be possible to read the map at the same time when a user is making a request.

Comment: Regarding the `sync.Map` vs `type AddrsMutex struct { sync.Mutex \n addrs string}`. I believe it is more performant with `sync.Mutex` instead of `sync.Map` since `sync.Map` require us to call `Range` method to mimic the `StartCleanExpiredAddrs()`, or am I wrong?

Comment: well either way you would have to loop though all the items so the range part should be the same as `for addr, val := range addrs {`  you are currently doing

Comment: I did a test, for my use case, `Sync.Map` needs 979.875µs, `Sync.Mutex` needs 401.833µs, `map[int]time.Time` needs `309.125µs`. The conclusion is `Sync.Mutex` is the better choice for my use case.